# AngularJS - Is Radio group selected?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular I have a group of radios ?
How to find if at least one is selected ?

**HTML:**

```
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='jayApp' ng-controller='jayController'>
  <h1>Angular radio group selected ??</h1>


  <input type="radio" name="country" ng-model='country'> India
  <input type="radio" name="country" ng-model='country'> UK
  <input type="radio" name="country" ng-model='country'> Germany
  <input type="radio" name="country" ng-model='country'> France

  <br>
  <br> A country selected ?? : {{country}}

</body>

</html>
```

Plunnker : http://embed.plnkr.co/cN6xhL/preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `value` to each `input`, so that angular has something to latch on to, and use ng-change if you just want to know that something has changed.

```
<input type="radio" name="country" ng-model='country' value='india' ng-change="change()"> India
<input type="radio" name="country" ng-model='country' value='uk'  ng-change="change()"> UK
<input type="radio" name="country" ng-model='country' value='germany' ng-change="change()"> Germany
<input type="radio" name="country" ng-model='country' value='france' ng-change="change()"> France
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GjW8LF?p=preview

Comment: Many thanks. Actually I am trying to find out if a radio box is selected or not ?

Comment: Jay: can you provide feedback on this answer now please